# How reduce job output data move to HBase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I want to know how reduce job on HDFS will insert into HBASE.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [o.a.h.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html) class. Here is the [code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.java) for the same.